# How to change Zoom button in PopupFeature with Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, popup, zoom, ol-ext

I'm using the code https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.popup.feature.html to create the Popup, to show the features information.

As can be seen in Figure 1, we have a magnifying glass in the popup.

[image]

The code for this button is:

```
// Zoom button
ol.ext.element.create('BUTTON', { className: 'ol-zoombt', parent: html })
.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (feature.getGeometry().getType()==='Point') {
    this.getMap().getView().animate({
      center: feature.getGeometry().getFirstCoordinate(),
      zoom:  Math.max(this.getMap().getView().getZoom(), 18)          
    });
  } else  {
    var ext = feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
    this.getMap().getView().fit(ext, { duration:1000 });
  }
}.bind(this));
```

When I click on the magnifying glass, it shows as shown in Figure 2.

[image]

How should I change the code, to show in a zoom closer to Figure 3?

[image]

Comment: Set `maxZoom` or `minResolution` in the options for `fit` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit (then you can use `fit` for any geometry type)

Comment: I didn't understand. I change it on this line? `zoom: Math.max(this.getMap().getView().getZoom(), 18)`

Comment: `this.getMap().getView().fit(ext, {duration:1000, maxZoom: Math.max(this.getMap().getView().getZoom(), 18)});`

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed.